# Mirroring an ASCII art

Tags: java, string, ascii

I'm trying to mirror this art vertically.

Example:

[image: From this]

[image: To this]

But here is what I ended up getting:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
String reverse;

for(int i=1;i<coolDragon.size();i++) // coolDragon is the name of the art. It is a txt file that I'm reading
{
    reverse = "";
    for (int j=coolDragon.get(i).length()-1;j>=0;j--) // probably the worst line of code
         reverse=reverse+coolDragon.get(i).charAt(j);
    System.out.println(reverse);
}
```

This is just reversing every string in every line. Is there some kind of padding I need to do here to get the perfect asymmetric reversal? Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You should find out which row of the input file has the most characters, and then you have to right pad each row with spaces, so that all rows have the same length before you reverse them.

For example, If you don't right pad the first row here with a single space :

```
XO
XXX
```

You'll get a reversed output of :

```
OX
XXX
```

When what you want is :

```
 OX
XXX
```

Also note that you are skipping the first line of the file. `i` should start from 0.

The code should look like this :

```
int maxLen = 0;
for(int i=0;i<coolDragon.size();i++) {
    if (cooDragon.get(i).length() > maxLen)
        maxLen = cooDragon.get(i).length();
}
StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(maxLen);
for(int i=0;i<coolDragon.size();i++) {
    reverse.setLnegth(0);
    for (int k=0; k<maxLen - coolDragon.get(i).length();k++) // add spaces
        reverse.append(' ');
    for (int j=coolDragon.get(i).length()-1;j>=0;j--) 
         reverse.append(coolDragon.get(i).charAt(j));
    System.out.println(reverse.toString());
}
```